# Sum of the inverse of subset areas of a domain

Tags: geometry

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a region composed by no overlap triangles $T$, and denote by $\textrm{area}(A)$ the area of a region $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

It is easy to see that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\Omega}\textrm{area}(T)=\textrm{area}(\Omega)\qquad (1)$$

*Exists $C(\textrm{area}(\Omega))$, not depending of the number of triangles of $\Omega$ and not depending of the size of the triangles $T$ (like the right hand side of the equation (1)), such that*

$$\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\Omega}\dfrac{1}{\textrm{area}(T)}\leq C(\textrm{area}(\Omega))?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a unit area triangle as $\Omega$. If you take it as formed by a single triangle, then $\sum_{T\in\Omega}1/\textrm{area}(T)=1$. But you can divide $\Omega$ into two triangles of area $1/2$ by drawing a median, in which case $\sum_{T\in\Omega}1/\textrm{area}(T)=4$. If then you halve those two triangles, obtaining four triangles of area $1/4$, then $\sum_{T\in\Omega}1/\textrm{area}(T)=16$. As you can see, this sequence diverges, so there is no hope to find a constant $C$ such that $\sum_{T\in\Omega}1/\textrm{area}(T)\le C$  for any subdivision of $\Omega$ into triangles.